# How do i call a variable(from mysql) onto a different page for each row?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a page that shows a list of products. Now for each row(product) i have column with a link that goes to a different page with the product information on it..

Now to load that information page, i need the product-number of the product(row) that has been clicked on.

I tried using a form with a GET method to send the product-number to the information page. But when i click on the information link, the page says i don't have permission to acces the page.

This is what i got;

```
include("intern_header.php");
include("../scripts/db_adreslist.php");
//query
$sql = "SELECT productnr,beschrijving FROM product";
//query uitvoeren
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo '<div class="container">';
  echo '<table class="table">';
  echo "<thead><tr><th>product-nummer</th><th>Omschrijving</th><th>details</th></tr></thead>";
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $productnr = $row["productnr"];
       $beschrijving = $row["beschrijving"];
       $more = "<form action = \"intern_producten_details.php\" method = \"GET\">
                <a href='../intern/intern_producten_details.php name=\"$productnr\"'>More..</a>
                </form>";
       echo "<tr><td style='width: 200px;'>".$productnr."
       </td><td style='width: 600px;'>".$beschrijving."</td>
       <td style='width: 100px;'>".$more."</td></tr>";
      }
  } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
```

the page loads with the product-number in the URL, but for some reason it says i don't have permission to acces the page.

this is the URL i get after clicking on the information link;

```
localhost/taak/intern/intern_producten_details.php%20name=%22prod007%22
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `href` link to

```
$more = "<form action = \"intern_producten_details.php\" method = \"GET\">
                <a href='../intern/intern_producten_details.php?name=\"$productnr\"'>More..</a>
                </form>";
```

You forgot to in the question (`?`) mark...